# JavaScript - неправильный вывод месяца

Tags: javascript

Бодрого всем кодинга
Вопрос:
Почему **time.getMonth()** выдаёт цифру от предыдущего месяца?
И как это исправить?
time.getMonth()+1 делает конкатенацию, но не сложение.

Comment: 1. [по определению](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). 
2. [http://javascript.ru/basic/operators](операторы и их особенности в JS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

простите за глупое предположение, но не пытаетесь ли вы месяцы считать с единицы? getMonth считает с нуля: январь это нулевой месяц, июнь — пятый, ноябрь десятый.

Comment: а вот насчёт конкатенации вы озадачили. getMonth возвращает целое число, и воспроизвести мне не удалось. Не могли бы вы на jsfiddle выложить образец странно ведущего себя кода?

а то у меня получается только так: http://jsfiddle.net/mb4nG/ — целые числа складываются

Comment: Всё, разобрался  
Немного почитал про getMonth() - эта функция оказывается возвращает не порядковый номер месяца, а его индекс! (Внезапно!)  
Чего же они дни так не сделали?

Comment: с днями была бы путаница похлеще.

Comment: @Елена Левина
это про конкатенацию: http://jsfiddle.net/mb4nG/1/  
А это уже исправленное: http://jsfiddle.net/Zyh6U/

Comment: они и сделали, например, в [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

    var days_of_week = ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'];
    console.log(days_of_week[(new Date()).getDay()]);

аналогично и месяцы.  
так было сделано в java, аналогично сделано в javascript'е.